# XP Remote Desktop Connection broken by remote assistance

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I've been using RDC to use another workstation downstairs. But today I can't get in except by restarting the target computer.  Once I've logged in, either locally or over RDC, I can't connect again. The RDC client just tells me that the target is not available, as if it was turned off.

Yet I can connect to a network share on the target, and read and write files on that share, and I can go downstairs and login or logout on the target.

After I restart the target, I get one successful RDC connection again. While I'm connected, I can let the target go to sleep, and wake it again.

FWIW, target XP, client Win7, nothing new installed, but this happened after using (once) "Remote Assistance" instead of RDC.

Edit: issued a new RA invitation from the target machine. Used the RA invitation from my (client) workstation. Entered the RA invitation password. Did NOT accept the response at the target (did not go downstairs and click "OK"), so the session timed out.  Imediately after, am able to open an RDC session from the my (client) workstation to the target.

Edit: By design, Terminal Services can't be stopped: all options like that are unavailable.

Any idea?

Comment: On the Windows XP machine (guessing by target you mean this is the machine you are remote desktoping on too) when the problem occurs or if you recreate the issue then go to Services and restart the Terminal Services Service, try to logon again remotely and let me know what the outcome is...

Comment: @CharlelsH unable to stop Terminal Services on XP. All options disabled, even with network and local admin users.